# Small question on the Kan-Quillen model structure on simplicial sets

Tags: model-categories

I would like to know two things about the Kan Quillen model structure on simplicial sets:

Firstly, let $|-|\dashv S$ be the geomtric realization, simplicial complex functor, and let $\eta_X$ be its unit on any simplicial set $X$. Is it true that $\eta_X$ is a weak-equivalence?

Secondly, is there an easy way to show that the map $X\rightarrow Map(\Delta^1,X)$ is a weak-equivalence? (If it is not, is there an obvious good path object on X, which is functorial?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adjunction is a Quillen equivalence and both functors preserve weak equivalences.
This means that the derived (co)units of this adjunction can be computed
as its (co)units.
In any Quillen equivalence the derived (co)units are weak equivalences.

The functor Map(−,X) preserves simplicial homotopy equivalences
and the map Δ^1→Δ^0 is a simplicial homotopy equivalence,
so the induced map X→Map(Δ^1,X) is a simplicial homotopy equivalence,
hence a weak equivalence.

The simplicial set Map(Δ^1,X) need not be a path object for X
because the endpoint map Map(Δ^1,X)→X×X need not be a fibration
if X is not fibrant.

This problem is typically resolved by fibrantly replacing X,
see for instance https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22642/is-there-a-combinatorial-way-to-factor-a-map-of-simplicial-sets-as-a-weak-equiva/